# JSF - Setting a property while following a link

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, prettyfaces

I'm using [prettyfaces](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/) for handling URL paths.

What I want to do is set a language property upon following a link (to choose language). Something like this:

```
<h:link outcome="#{bean.currentPath}" value="English"> <!-- path goes to self -->
    <f:param name="link" value="#{currentTopic.link}" />
    <f:param name="lang" value="eng" />
</h:link>
```

The prettyconfig retrieves the link and follows it, but how can I send the parameter to the language bean?

```
<url-mapping id="">
    <pattern value="/topic/#{link:bean.link}" />
    <view-id>/faces/topic.jsf</view-id>
</url-mapping>
```

The bean is stateless (@RequestScoped) and the language bean is stateful (@SessionScoped). Both are @ManagedBeans.

Comment: is it possible to add it to your exisitng url pattern? /topic/#{link:bean.link}/#{lang:languageBean.lang}

Comment: I've considered it, however my professor here at the uni. said language should be defined completely on the serverside, without having it in the URL for the user to see because it's only defined once.

Comment: This is however a huge SEO disadvantage. Content in different languages would be marked as duplicate content this way.

Comment: +1 BalusC -- your site would benefit greatly by making the content available for each language on a distict url so that they can be indexed independently.

Comment: Ah I see. Good point. I'll consider switching over to the solution you've provided Dave, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option for you that still uses rest urls. It's not extremely elegant but probably accomplishes what you're looking for:

```
<pretty:link mappingId="LanguageTopic">
    <f:param name="link" value="#{currentTopic.link}" />
    <f:param name="lang" value="eng" />
    English
</pretty:link>
```

pretty-config.xml:

```
<url-mapping id="LanguageTopic">
    <pattern value="/topic/#{link:linkBean.link}/#{lang:languageBean.lang}/" />
    <view-id>/faces/topic.jsf</view-id>
    <action>#{linkBean.cleanUrl}</action>
</url-mapping>

<url-mapping id="Topic">
    <pattern value="/topic/#{link:linkBean.link}/" />
    <view-id>/faces/topic.jsf</view-id>
</url-mapping>
```

language bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "languageBean")
@SessionScoped
public class LanguageBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4460586548949990787L;

    /**
     * Stores the users language preference
     */
    private String lang;

    public String getLang() { return this.lang; }
    public void setLang(String lang) { this.lang = lang; }

}
```

link bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "linkBean")
@RequestScoped
public class LinkBean {

    /**
     * Stores the resource the user is currently accessing
     */
    private String link;

    public String getLink() { return this.link; }
    public void setLink(String link) { this.link = link; }

    /**
     * Cleans language specific rest urls to non-specific urls
     */
    public void cleanUrl() {
        final ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

        try {
            externalContext.redirect("/topic/" + this.link + "/");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //log or whatever you want here
        }    
    }
}
```